# Groovy/Grails many-to-many delete relation

Tags: grails, groovy

I have 2 domain class with a many to many relationship. When I delete the entity that belongs to the other, I have to remove the relation before in order to avoid a foreign key error. These relations are connected via the third class, third table in MySQL.

```
class City {
    String nameCity     
    static hasMany = [visits:Visit]

    /* FIRST VARIANT. REMOVES ONE VISIT ONLY */
     def beforeDelete() {
         Visit.withNewSession {
             def visitList = Visit.findByCity(this)
             visitList.each { it.delete(flush: true) }
         }
        }
    }
//_____________________________________________
class Visit {        // it is the relation class
    City city
    Person person
}
//_____________________________________________
class Person {
    String namePerson
    static hasMany = [visits:Visit]
}
```

So when I delete the relation between two classes, it removes one relation only. I mean, if we have 1 City and 1 Person, and try to delete this City, the app functions OK. But if you have more than one Person attached to the City, we will have:
"Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails". But one relation is deleted.
If I try to delete the City one more time, the second Person will be deleted. My app behaves like that until the last Person to be deleted. So, beforeDelete() method works great.
My problem is I don't understand how to create a collection of relations and remove them all in a cycle (loop). If I make like this:

```
class City {
    String nameCity
    static hasMany = [visits:Visit]

    /* SECOND VARIANT. TYPE CAST EXCEPTION   */
     Collection<Visit> visitList() {
        Visit.findByCity(this)
    }

     def beforeDelete() {
         Visit.withNewSession {
             visitList().each { it.delete(flush: true) }

}
}
         }
```

I have org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.typehandling.GroovyCastException 'Cannot cast object 'mypackage.Visit : 1' with class 'mypackage.Visit' to class 'java.util.Collection'.
Any thoughts and help highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried the following? In theory should work...

```
class City {
    String nameCity     
    static hasMany = [visits:Visit]



class Visit {        // it is the relation class
    City city
    Person person
    static belongsTo = [city:City, person:Person]
}

class Person {
    String namePerson
    static hasMany = [visits:Visit]
}
```

And just make a normal delete. In this way, if you delete a City or a Person, all its related visits will be deleted

Comment: Now it functions flawlessly. And the problem decision is so short and nice. Thanks, Eylen!